# Name too long for e-ticket. Should I be worried?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, children, filipino-citizens, philippines

I recently bought a ticket for my whole family online. I have a daughter who is almost a year old.

Everything's fine, but then I noticed that they cut her name short. Here is the example of the name (not her real name) as shown on her passport.

To reiterate, this name is a pseudonym:

> SURNAME - RIVERA
>   NAME - Chanelle Elize
>   Middle name - Mendoza

On her e-ticket it shows:

> RIVERA Chanelle E M

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I'm worried that they would make a big deal out of this.

Comment: All: Please note that there is no need to protect anyone's privacy by editing the name in the question.  It is already a pseudonym.

Comment: I noticed it was a pseudonym right after I submitted the suggestion and wanted to take it back. :)

Comment: I wonder if the ticketing systems always uses initials, even if the full name would fit.

Answer (score 26):

**Don't worry!**  Full middle names are never required on flight tickets, and even the initials are usually not needed.  As long as the rest of the name and the initials match the passport, she will be fine.

Comment: I used a third party website and I wrote her name correctly. Her name is not even complete. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Small addition: For flights to the US (from outside the US), the name in the electronic ticket must match precisely what is written on the passport. That doesn't mean that the name cannot be abbreviated on printouts and boarding passes, though.

Comment: "Full middle names are never required on flight tickets" - Good to know, and explains why I've never had trouble with tickets having my middle name and license not (presumably a common occurrence and contributing in no small part to that policy).

Comment: @DCTLib It doesn't matter that much, small changes can be corrected at the airport. Sometimes I travel under the name "Jon" or "John" (on the ticket, not just boarding pass) instead of "Jonathan". It's not a problem.

Comment: Can anyone cite the actual rules about names? The TSA says [_small differences shouldn't matter_](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/id/secure.aspx#DoesNameOnTicketMatch) but they don't define  "small differences", and then they go on to say that _You should ensure that the name provided for Secure Flight when booking your travel matches the government ID_, which seems to contradict their previous statement.

Comment: @Johnny Best practise: names should be identical. In reality, the name just clearly needs to be the same person. So using a common shorthand or alternative spelling, or swapping first/middle is not going to be a problem. But you are dealing with TSA (or other security), the airline (revenue protection) and border control (immigration) who may all have their own requirements.

Comment: @Johnny Also, "The name you provide when booking your travel" does not necessarily equal what gets recorded in the e-ticket and/or printed on the ticket.

Comment: Ok, but what should you do if your **first name** is e.g. "John Abbas" and e.g. **last name** is ‌"Smith Alexandrian Minnesota". I'm not asking this for the sake of its pleasure. A friend of mine just reached out to me and said "every airline I reserve a ticket they say my last name is too long and we can't do it"

Comment: @Honey How is the name written in their passport?

Comment: Given name is 4 characters. Surname is: 9 + 22 characters

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when I travel as my name is extremely long as well. I've had them cut my name off, combine the names into one, and do all sorts of other things. But I have never had problems. I am sure the name is accurately documented somewhere in the system, it's just a space issue on any printed confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are flying to the United States of America, you should be worried. In the last 1.5 years (since our youngest was born) we already missed two flights because she has 3 first names, that usually don't fit on the ticket. Which means extra checks and longer waiting times.

The USA is very strict (for good reasons) and it has to be a perfect match with the passport.

Only the details on your passport and ticket matter. Even if you have a print out of a customer service email saying it's ok, that still isn't a valid ticket for boarding. It usually comes down to the willingness of the airline/airport staff and their supervisor during check-in, so allow for extra time during the whole check-in process (in our experience up to 3 hours).

Comment: so I take it that you didn't include her entire first name into the ticket? And later at the gate explain and convince the officer?