# Surname too long for airline ticket

Tags: tickets, airlines, bookings

I've already seen [Name too long for e-ticket. Should I be worried?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49865/name-too-long-for-e-ticket-should-i-be-worried). But that question is focused on the **middle name** which isn't that important. This is about the **surname**. I also left a comment on the accepted answer but received no reply.

The name I'm asking for is:

Given name is 4 characters. **Surname is: 9 (space) 22 characters**

Currently all airlines are refusing to allow my friend to purchase a ticket. What can they do about it?

Comment: I believe you can short the last name, the best option is to ask to the air company. Here you can see some also -> https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108929/am-i-going-to-have-trouble-flying-without-my-full-name-on-the-ticket/108942#108942

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name too long for e-ticket. Should I be worried?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49865/name-too-long-for-e-ticket-should-i-be-worried)

Comment: @MarcelP I already linked to that question. That question has a focus on middleName. This is about surname which is far more important.

Comment: Can you describe the reason given by the airlines for the refusal to sell a ticket?  If the reason is "your surname is too long," do they give a maximum length they will accept?  Is your friend's complete name displayed on the identification document your friend plans to use to fly on this trip?

Comment: @phoog "Is your friend's complete name displayed on the identification document your friend plans to use to fly on this trip?". Supposedly. But let me make sure.

Comment: It may be relevant that in some countries you can have entered into your passport an "also known as" name, for example if a person is still known by their per-marriage family name for professional reasons. Perhaps this can help in some cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My friend told that she was trying to buy through third party websites. Through them she wasn't able to purchase the ticket. They were canceling the ticket...

Once she directly reached out to an airline, she got the matter resolved. They bought the ticket with the first 9 characters of the last name, but QatarAirways employee said we'll enter into the system the remaining (22) characters ourselves.

FWIW she got her ticket through Qatar Airlines...